# How to restart automatically the server after the backup is done

Tags: wbadmin, backup

I would like to restart my server once the backup job is done.

I launch the backup job at the commande line using

> wbadmin start backup [options]

This command only starts backup and exits. Therefore it is not possible to use something like this, because the server would restart immediately:

> wbadmin start backup [options]
>   shutdown -r

Is there a solution to execute the backup and the restart with the same scheduled task, or do I simply have to schedule two tasks at a reasonable interval ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would presume that you could schedule a task based on the Event ID 4 in the event logs to kick off a reboot after it is posted.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734345%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

```
Product:    Windows Operating System
ID:     4
Source:     Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Version:    6.0
Symbolic Name:  BACKUP_SUCCESS_EVENT
Message:    Backup finished successfully.
```

Simply right clicking the event log entry and choosing "Attach task to event" should get you there. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748900.aspx

Comment: This is a great answer. I learnt about attaching a task to an event, which will come in handy many times.

Comment: You might want EventID 19 as well.  19 is a backup failed to start..  This would reboot even if the backup failed.  Assuming you want it  to do that..  I use it for emailing me a notification of backup failure as you don't get an EventID 4 when it fails...

Comment: Yeah, all the events associated with Windows Backup can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734488%28v=ws.10%29.aspx - so feel free to queue off of whatever is showing up in your logs as best as you see fit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`get status`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742050.aspx) argument to `wbadmin`. It won't return until the job completes, so it would be fairly trivial to write a script that kicked-off the backup, fired off a `wbadmin get status`, and then did whatever you want after the backup completes.